Why do we need Type Erasure given we already have parameterized protocols
We have many type erasure classes like AnyPublisher in Combine framework. But why do need them at all, as we already have parameterized protocols?
For example, why don't we just replace let myPublisher = AnyPublisher<Int, Never> with any Publisher<Int, Never>? The only difference I can tell is that type erasure gives us existential types, but why do we care?


But why do need them at all, as we already have parameterized protocols? (emphasis added)

Combine (released in iOS 13) is several years older than primary associated types (what you're calling "parameterized protocols"). While most things you can do with AnyPublisher you can today do with any Publisher, that was not true a pretty short time ago. Combine has had almost no updates in several years since async came out (and most of the updates were to provide async compatibility). If you were designing Combine from scratch today, you probably could get away without AnyPublisher. But that wasn't true when it was designed, and it is all but abandoned by Apple, so I wouldn't expect major changes.

Combine is just an example I think of immediately. The question I had applies to all type erasures objects. Technically we don't need type erasure any more, is this correct?

In many cases we do not. We still do if the protocol has a non-primary associated type that you want to constrain, or if you want to constrain an associated type in a way other than a "same-type" constraint. There is no "generalized" form of this currently. For example, several of the use cases described here still require a type eraser: https://forums.swift.org/t/protocol-assoctype-t-shorthand-for-combined-protocol-and-associated-type-constraints-without-naming-the-constrained-type/21217

That article is complicated, but thanks for explaining! Sounds like type erasure is still needed in certain scenarios even though we now have parameterized protocols
